# Are external pullup resistors required D I/O pins on RN4870/71?

Tags: pullup

Are external pull-up resistors required on RN4870/71 for pins like "P1_1"? The [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/RN4870-71-Bluetooth-Low-Energy-Module-Data-Sheet-DS50002489D.pdf) mentions D I/O pins being "pulled-high", is it pulled high with internal resistors or programmatically from the microcontroller it's connected to or are external pullup resistors required?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Datasheet pg 11]

According to datasheet pg 11, there is a pull-up resistance of ~50kΩ. If the pins are naturally pulled high, it must be enabled by default. However, be careful, 50kΩ is a pretty weak pull up, you may need to add in a smaller external resistor if pull up speed is a critical concern (Low pass formed with parasitic capacitance and pull-up resistance, bigger R, larger tau, slower response time).